# The code works when its typed in phpmyadmin but not working in my web site

Tags: php, sql

The code work fine in the phpmyadmin but when i try to do it with php from the website it doesn't change the value :/ help !?

```
enter code here
<?php
    include_once 'logiranje.php';
    $maticen = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['maticenpromena']);
    $naziv = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['nazivsmetka']);
    if ($naziv=="Participacija") 
    {
        $naziv = "101010";
    }
    else if ($naziv=="Materijali") //problem here it was IF instead of ELSE IF
    {
        $naziv = "202020";
    }
    else
        $naziv = "303030";
    $mesec = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['mesec']);
    $godina = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['godina']);
    $sql = "UPDATE imaat SET imaat.platena=true WHERE imaat.embg=$maticen AND 
imaat.id_smetka= $naziv AND imaat.mesec=$mesec AND 
imaat.godina=$godina;";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
header("Location: ../smetki.php?platenasmetka=success");
?>
```

Comment: getting errors ????

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: `echo $sql;` before `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
` and share the result

Comment: Quote the values in the query or better use a prepared statement.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

your sql is not correct, try with this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE imaat SET imaat.platena=true WHERE imaat.embg=".$maticen." AND 
imaat.id_smetka=". $naziv." AND imaat.mesec=".$mesec." AND 
imaat.godina=".$godina;
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE imaat SET imaat.platena=true WHERE imaat.embg='$maticen' AND 
imaat.id_smetka='$naziv' AND imaat.mesec='$mesec' AND 
imaat.godina='$godina'";
```

> when you insert $var inside your query , you are not put the value of
>   variable , but the word $var that why , he can't find a row thoses
>   variables names.

Comment: but who knows `godina` and `maticenpromena` are string values of integer.

Comment: i don't get what you say

Comment: if both of them having string value then this query will not work.

Comment: did you try it ?

Comment: as i think there is not issue with OP query. maybe he is having string value, but i cant predict until unless OP share the exact error message

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI nope. PHP will replace $something with the string value of $something when in a double-quote string expression, and a simple expression (a var for example).

Comment: Yeah this helped me :D also i had a problem with the if else statements because when i choose the first one on the else it will change $naziv='303030. Thanks all :D '